# Is there a way to know which object received objc_release message?

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, exc-bad-access

Getting crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, stack symbols look like this:

```
po [NSThread callStackSymbols]
<_NSCallStackArray 0x608000052c60>(
0   ???                                 0x00000001077e66cd 0x0 + 4420691661,
1   Flume-Debug                         0x000000010003ee60 main + 0,
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffdbde90fc _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage11tls_deallocEPv + 110,
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffdc8eb50f _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 544,
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffdc8eb249 _pthread_exit + 152,
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffdc8e9ab6 pthread_sigmask + 0,
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffdc8e99f7 _pthread_body + 0,
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffdc8e91fd thread_start + 13
)
```

My platform ix x86_64, so I [tried examining](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html) registers `$rdi` and `$rsi` without much luck:

```
po [(id)$rdi class]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40dedeadbec8).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Is that even possible? Since the message has already been sent and caused crashed due to bad receiver's address. Enabling `NSZombie` doesn't help - code crashes at the same point with no additional useful information.

Looking and the backtrace, should I question myself - "which object has been added to autorelease pool but was manually/early deallocated?" to figure out the problem?

Comment: Don't use `po [NSThread callStackSymbols]` to get a backtrace in the debugger, just use `bt`. You don't appear to have crashed in `objc_msgSend()` or the like, so that linked article is not directly relevant. Rather than trying to enable `NSZombie` manually, which is error prone, have you tried running in Instruments using the Zombies template? Besides a use-after-free bug, you might have a memory smasher. You might try [enabling Guard Malloc (a.k.a. libgmalloc)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html).

Comment: i suppose it's Allocations instrument with NSZombie detection enabled. unfortunately it doesn't show anything, letting app to crash.